# question about trigonometric function transformation

Tags: trigonometry

what is the difference between 
$\cos^2(\theta - 180) $ and  $\cos^2(180 - \theta) $ Does $\\cosec^2(450 + \theta)$ transform into $\sec$?

Comment: The difference is $0$, because $\cos x = \cos (-x)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos(180^\circ-x)=\cos180^\circ\cos x+\sin18^\circ\sin x=\cos x\cdot(-1)$$

$$\cos(x-180^\circ)=\cos x\cos180^\circ+\sin x\sin18^\circ=(-1)\cos x$$

$$\csc(450^\circ+y)=\cos\{360^\circ+(90^\circ+y)\}=\csc(90^\circ+y)$$

Now $\sin(90^\circ+y)=\sin90^\circ\cos y+\cos90^\circ\sin y=\cos y$

Answer (score 0):

$cos^2(\theta - 180) = cos^2(180 - \theta)$

Comment: $\cos(\theta-180^{\circ})^2=\cos(\theta)^2$ and $\cos(180^{\circ}-\theta)^2=\cos(\theta)^2$

Comment: your answer is wrong, please edit this

Answer (score 0):

$$cosec^2(450+\theta)=\frac{1}{sin^2(450+\theta)}\\= \frac{1}{sin^2(360+90+\theta)}=\\\frac{1}{sin^2(90+\theta)}=\\\frac{1}{cos^2(\theta)}$$

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between $\cos^2 (\theta-180)$ & $\cos^2 (\theta-180)$ since, $$ \cos (-\theta)=\cos (\theta)$$ $$\implies \cos^2 (\theta-180)=(\cos (\theta-180))^2$$$$=(\cos(-(180-\theta)))^2=(\cos (180-\theta))^2=\cos^2(180-\theta)$$ Notice, $$cosec^2(450+\theta)=cosec^2(360+90+\theta)$$ $$=cosec^2(90+\theta)$$ $$=sec^2(\theta)$$